# Как сделать placeholder для select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-select

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе, к примеру, `США`, слова `Выбранная страна` оставались. То есть `Выбранная страна:` постоянно должны быть внутри независимо от выбора страны.

```html
<select name="country">
  <option value disabled selected>Выбранная страна: Россия</option>
  <option>Россия</option>
  <option>США</option>
  <option>Турция</option>
  <option>Китай</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Без js тут не обойтись

Comment: Есть примеры на js? Просто не могу загуглить даже это

Comment: Примеров нет, но можнот написать самому

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать еще 1 элемент с текстом "Выбранная страна:" с абсолютным позиционированием на нужном месте, а внутри селекта добавить отступ слева.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Сделать можно так:

1. помещаем `select` в отдельный контейнер, например, `.block`;
2. добавляем в `.block` еще один блок, например, `.placeholder`, в который будем выводить текст "Выбранная страна:" + текст выбранной `option`, и располагаем его поверх `select`;
3. для `.placeholder` в css указываем `pointer-events:none;`, чтобы не
   припятствовать клику по `select`

На jQuery это будет выглядеть вот так:

```js
function selPlaceholder(block) {
  var placeholder = block.find('.placeholder'),
    select = block.find('select');
  placeholder.text(placeholder.attr('data-text') + select.find('option:selected').text());
}

$('.block').each(function() {
  selPlaceholder($(this));
});

$('.block select').on('change', function() {
  selPlaceholder($(this).closest('.block'));
});
```

```css
.block,
.block select {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px;
}

.block .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 5px;
  top: 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="placeholder" data-text="Выбранная страна: "></div>
  <select name="country">
    <option>Россия</option>
    <option>США</option>
    <option>Турция</option>
    <option>Китай</option>
  </select>
</div><br /><br />
<div class="block">
  <div class="placeholder" data-text="Выбранный тип аккаунта: "></div>
  <select name="type">
    <option>Бесплатный</option>
    <option>Профессиональный</option>
    <option>Для бизнеса</option>
  </select>
</div><br /><br />
<div class="block">
  <div class="placeholder" data-text="Выбранная валюта: "></div>
  <select name="currency">
    <option>USD</option>
    <option>EUR</option>
    <option>RUB</option>
    <option>UAH</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сталкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. После долгих мучений придумал выход на CSS

```css
.div_wrap{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.select{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
}
/* Вид Placeholder */
.label{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #687a86;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
/* Здесь то что будет происходить с Placeholder'ом после изменения select */
.select:valid+.label {
  color: black;
  top: -35px;
  width: 300px;

}
```

```html
<div class="div_wrap">
  <select required class="select">
    <option selected value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
    <option value="2">Пункт 2</option>
    <option value="3">Пункт 3</option>
  </select>
  <label class="label">Ваш Выбор:</label>
</div>
```